# No module named syslog (Module Not Found Error) while using awsretry module

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I am using `awsretry` module on my `windows` machine to try and alter the number of retries/API query request rate to my `aws` services.

Below is my code which is pretty straightforward.

```
import boto3
from awsretry import AWSRetry


@AWSRetry.backoff()
def create_service():

    client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
    for i in range(200):
       print(client.list_notebook_instances())


create_service()
```

I am getting the below error.

```
 from awsretry import AWSRetry
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
  32\lib\site-packages\awsretry\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import syslog
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'syslog'
```

How do I resolve this? Looks like `awsretry` internally has dependency on `syslog` module. I tried installing this via pip, but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **virtualenv** as shown in `awsretry` documentation [here](https://github.com/linuxdynasty/awsretry#development) instead of the `pip install awsretry`.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.That worked. But why doesnt the pip install work?

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as it would be good to know

Just went through the `GitHub` link of awsretry and they have fixed this issue by replacing 
`syslog` with `logging`. Syslog requires Linux.

```
import syslog # Removed
import logging # Added
```

Below is the link for the fix

https://github.com/jhart-r7/awsretry/commit/ddd98a2797b8ef1f6d6311edfc71e2b7fc631877

If you have the code, you may replace `syslog` occurences with `logging` line in `__init__.py`